# How to set AViewController (subclass of TabBar and Nav Controller) to portrait only

Tags: ios, autorotate, portrait

If I have AViewController which is a subclass of TabBarController and NavigationController, is it possible to set it to portrait? while, the other ViewController can rotate normally. (Portrait and Landscape)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. You can find the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html). You just have to override a few methods and return supported orientations for each view controller, such as supportedInterfaceOrientations and preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation methods.

For example, to limit the orientation to portrait you would do

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    return interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

Edit:

I added the preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation method. Try this. This is the exact code i'm using in one of our apps, and it is working for us.

Comment: I try preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation and return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait; it doesn't work though.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Is it rotating when it shouldn't? Do you want a view controller to stick to portrait? Or don't they rotate when they should? I may help if you provide more info. Did you selected supported orientations for the app in project view?

Comment: It's rotating when it shouldn't. Yes, I want a view controller to stick to portrait. and yes, I do selected supported orientations for the app in project view (portrait, landscape left, landscape right)

Comment: I updated my answer. I copied/pasted the same code I'm using. It should work. I added the preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation method.